# Get sub string or string tokenize from a large string

Tags: c#, string

I have a sting like this:

```
(Project in ("CI") and Status in ("Open") and issueType in ("Action Item")) or issueKey = "GR L-1" order by Created asc
```

I want to parse this to get like below:

```
string st1 = "CI";
string str2 = "Open";
string str3 = "Action Item";
```

I tried with this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7664/StringTokenizer

This is what I have tried:

```
 string input = @"(Project in (""CI"") and Status in (""Open"") and issueType in (""Action Item"")) or issueKey = ""GR L-1"" order by Created asc";

        string sub = input.Substring(13, 3);
```

Note: The string I'm going to retrieve can change dynamically.

I'm not getting as expected. Could you one please guide?

Comment: Modified question, what I have tried.

Comment: Come on - `input.Substring(13, 3);` returns the string `"CI`.  It shouldn't be that hard to figure out that you're off by one, and taking too many characters.

Comment: My string is going to change, so I can not hard code it. Now it CI, later it could be "AABB C".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is using regular expressions, try this code

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class RegexTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourcestring = @"(Project in (""CI"") and Status in (""Open"") and issueType in (""Action Item"")) or issueKey = ""GR L-1"" order by Created asc";

        var mc = Regex.Matches(sourcestring,
                               @"\(""(?<word>[A-Za-z0-9\s]+)""\)");

        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            foreach (Capture cap in m.Groups["word"].Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cap.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output result will be the words you're looking for.

```
CI 
Open 
Action Item
```

Test the code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RHpf3n) https://dotnetfiddle.net/RHpf3n

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement looks as if you want to extract any data that is found between `("` & `")`.  If you find `Regex` to be a little "intimidating" you can still use your attempted `String.Substring()` approach, you just also have to combine it with `String.IndexOf()` to get the index locations of `("` & `")` and provide those values to your `String.Substring()` instead of trying to hard code them.

One way of doing this could look like the following:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"(Project in (""CI"") and Status in (""Open"") and issueType in (""Action Item"")) or issueKey = ""GR L-1"" order by Created asc";

        // Find the open paren & quote
        int startIndex = input.IndexOf("(\"", 0);

        // Loop until we don't find an open paren & quote
        while (startIndex > -1)
        {
            // Find the closing paren & quote
            int endIndex = input.IndexOf("\")", startIndex);

            Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(startIndex + 2, endIndex - startIndex - 2));

            // Find the next open paren & quote
            startIndex = input.IndexOf("(\"", endIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
CI
Open
Action Item
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WNJOFg)

Comment: Hey , I didn't know about Fiddle, I hope you don't get mad if I use it in my answer.

Comment: @JuanK Not at all, even users that post answers learn something :-)